# unable to deploy mysql externally in docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I have installed MYSQL(8.0.16) in my host system and trying to deploy in docker which failing and getting the below error

DOCKER COMMAND I HAVE USED:

> docker run -e LICENSE="accept" -e TZ="Asia/Kolkata" -d --name=Sample2b2bi --net=host -v C:/data1:/ibm/resources 51fd2c55dd7b b2bi_setup deploy_db

AS PER LOGS I am getting as :

```
docker logs -t 8f1d73dd7d0e4b6b8aaa89ec502021ef9174f699d5f8e4274735787e638710a9
': not a valid identifier0900Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier9200Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier2900Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier8300Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier8900Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier9500Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier7400Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier6400Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier2200Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier7600Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
': not a valid identifier0600Z /ibm/b2bi/install/bin/b2biDockerStart.sh: line 69: export: `
2019-07-09T16:27:17.918354900Z Accepted license terms and conditions...
2019-07-09T16:27:18.276083500Z Failed to get a connection with the configured database parameters due to error : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. Please make sure the following database configurations are correct - DB_USER | DB_PASSWORD | DB_HOST | DB_PORT | DB_DATA | DB_DRIVERS
2019-07-09T16:27:18.290265300Z cp: cannot stat '/ibm/resources/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar'$'\r': No such file or directory
2019-07-09T16:27:18.290645300Z Failed to setup docker instance with exit code 1. Exiting...
2019-07-09T16:27:18.291068600Z Failed to validate configuration for docker instance. Exiting...
```

Comment: can you remove double quotes in -e option and try docker run again.

Comment: @mchawre getting the same issue ..I am docker for windows

Comment: hum...The line "cp: cannot stat '/ibm/resources/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar'$'\r':" could indicate a problem with special characters in a script  . Check this thread and see if it helps: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/what-does-cp-cannot-stat-mean-640617/

Comment: @camba1 renamed "mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar" to mysqljdbc.jar still getting the same issue

Comment: Hmmm I am not very familiar with docker for windows but is this part ok? C:/data1:/ibm/resources ... shouldnt you use backslashes (\\) on Windows? C:\data1?

Comment: @ishkk467 How about the \r? is it still part of the error in the log? \r is a windows a windows only carriage return and may be the script in linux is interpreting it as part of the file name somewhere in your script?